# JavaScript comparison involving method is never true

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I have the following JavaScript logical condition using the ternary operator:

```
var columnheader = (elem.getText === "ID") ? (Page.TableColumn(elem.getText())) : (Page.TableColumn(toTitleCase(elem.getText())));
```

For some reason when elem.getText value is 'ID' *with no whitespace* it doesn't evalute the first expression only the second, is there something wrong in my syntax? I've checked and double checked!

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis. But your syntax is fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `elem.getText() === "ID"`? otherwise can't find anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

getText is a function. In your code, you are comparing the function with "ID", not the result of the function call (getText() ).

Should be:

```
var columnheader = (elem.getText() ==="ID") ? (Page.TableColumn(elem.getText())) : (Page.TableColumn(toTitleCase(elem.getText())));
```

Comment: Thanks it was failing at runtime I thought the compiler would have shown this type of error as getText is not a string.